# Change cursor origin dynamically with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, cursor, offset

Is there a way to access the cursor via javascript so that you can define the x, y position of the image?
I have a custom data-uri set for the cursor in css, and I want to be able to adjust the offset dynamically without having to redefine the whole thing.

```
body{
    cursor: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" height="48" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M 0 0 H 6 L 12 12 V 18"/></svg>') 24 24, auto;
}
```

How would I set just the x, y via javascript dynamically??

Comment: What is your goal exactly?

Comment: goal is to adjust the offset based on mouse positon, but I just realized that it would be based on lagged positions due to mousemove event latency.. I guess even if I could offset it, it wouldn't accomplish what I need it to.

Comment: I basically wanted the cursor to snap to an invisible grid.

Comment: You might want to take a look at pointer locking: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_Lock_API

Answer (score 0):

In case you do want to have a look at pointer locking, here's a jQuery-free implementation.

```js
var getPointerLock = () => {
  if (document.body.mozRequestPointerLock) {
    document.body.mozRequestPointerLock();
  } else if (document.body.requestPointerLock) {
    document.body.requestPointerLock();
  }
};

var x = 0;
var y = 0;

document.body.onclick = (evt) => {
  getPointerLock();
  x = evt.clientX;
  y = evt.clientY;
};

document.body.onmousemove = (evt) => {
  if (document.pointerLockElement || document.mozPointerLockElement) {
    x += evt.movementX;
    y += evt.movementY;
    document.body.innerHTML = `${x}, ${y}`;
  }
};
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Does this have the same latency issue as mousemove?

Comment: ah, did some tests, and it does have same latency. Reason why I was using css cursor was because it has no visual latency.

Comment: The actual mouse is consumed when pointer locked, so a normal user won't notice any latency since the actual mouse position isn't redrawn, something that does happen in your example. Once you've calculated the new cursor-position, redrawing the cursor is completely up to you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the latency you're talking about? For me, the example in https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/pointer-lock/ is pretty much lag-free :) Are you sure the latency problems aren't coming from a different source?

Comment: The pointerlock has the same issue as mousemove, just that you can't see it clearly because the cursor has been hidden. The coordinates aren't accurate to the mouse position as it moves due to the latency of the events.